# Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ well-defined as a standalone operator?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, notation

I'm trying to formalise the ideas behind $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$.
[This post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115416/if-d-dx-is-an-operator-on-what-does-it-operate) answered my questions regarding $\frac{d}{dx}$ very well, but I'm still not sure if $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is actually meaningful without more context.

Based on one of the answers from the above post, my understanding is that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is not well-defined as a standalone operator and whenever we write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ we are assuming it is defined on the manifold constructed from the variables (viewed as functions) of some previously defined function.
Hence when we write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_1$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_2$, if $f_1$ and $f_2$ have different variables, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is actually the same notation used for two different functions. Is this correct?

Comment: When defining an operator, we must specify its domain. In other words, we must specify the space of functions on which the operator is defined.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is not meaningful without context. The meaning of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f$ depends on which variable of $f$ is called $x$.

If $f_1(x, y)=2x+y$ then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_1=2$.

If $f_2(y, x)=2y+x$ then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_2=1$.

$f_1$ and $f_2$ are set-theoretically the same function, but $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_1$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_2$ differ depending on which variable is $x$.

Comment: I’d disagree. $f_1=f_2$ so if $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f_1)$ has to equal $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f_2)$… assuming of course, as OP seems to want to, we want to interpret $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ as an operator (in particular a *function* from one set to another set, rather than a mere *relation*). The only correct part of this answer is that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is not meaningful without context; but the example you chose to illustrate with is not good. I agree there is something to be said about ordering, but what you wrote is not it.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think my answer is correct, but I will wait for you to write the correct answer first rather than refute it.

Comment: I’m just making the simple statement that for an operator, equal inputs $(f_1=f_2)$ must result in equal outputs. Once I have made a definition for the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, say as a mapping $C^1(\Bbb{R}^2)\to C^0(\Bbb{R}^2)$ , then I can say “define the function $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ by setting for each $(@,\#)\in\Bbb{R}^2$, $f(@,\#):=2@+\#$”, and I will get an unambiguous value for $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(f)$. THe choice of letters used for the inputs of the function $f$ is irrelevant if I have already made a precise definition for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Of course, if one is faced with the formal expression $2x+y$ vs $2y+x$ then one would like to symbolically define $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ to have value $2,1$ respectively, but that’s another matter.

Comment: @peek-a-boo $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is a notation for symbolic differentiation. In variable-free contexts $\partial_1, \partial_2, …$ is preferred to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, …$. It is odd to define $f(y, x)=2y+x$ and calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f=2$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think if you disagree with what Power wrote we could define $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ as a mapping $\mathbb{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}) \to L^1(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N})$ in which case it would be well defined without any further context. Since under this assumption we always know which variable corresponds to $x$ we just need to define $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ as a function of all differentiable functions.